# Requirejs create empty module to serve as a dependency loader

Tags: javascript, highcharts, requirejs

I would like to create a module in the require config that does not exist but is there only to load dependencies. For example:

```
window["requirejs"].config({
            paths: {
              main  :   "/Scripts/" +  "/main",
              jquery  :   "/Scripts/" +  "/jquery-2.1.3.min",
              HiChartsWithExtensions : false,//what to put here???
              HighCharts  :   "/Scripts/" +  "/HighCharts/highcharts",
              HighChartsExporting  :   "/Scripts/" +  "/HighCharts/modules/exporting",
              HighChartsExportingCsv  :   "/Scripts/" +  "/HighCharts/modules/export-csv",
            }
            , shim : {
              main : {
                deps : ["HiChartsWithExtensions"]
              },
              HiChartsWithExtensions : {
                deps : ["HighChartsExporting"]
              },
              HighCharts: {
                deps : ["jquery"],
                exports: '$'
              },
              "HighChartsExporting" : {
                deps : ["HighCharts"]
              },
              "HighChartsExportingCsv" : {
                deps : ["HighChartsExporting"]
              }
            }
});
window["require"](['main']);
```

Where main depends on HiChartsWithExtensions but requirejs tries to load a js file for it. I would like HiChartsWithExtensions to load dependencies without that module actually returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

For now; the following solution helped:

```
window["requirejs"].config({
            paths: {
              main  :   "/Scripts/" +  "/main",
              jquery  :   "/Scripts/" +  "/jquery-2.1.3.min",
              HiChartsWithExtensions : "/Scripts/" +  "/HighCharts/modules/export-csv",
              //deepest dependency here (csv depends on exporting depends on highcharts)
              HighCharts  :   "/Scripts/" +  "/HighCharts/highcharts",
              HighChartsExporting  :   "/Scripts/" +  "/HighCharts/modules/exporting",
              HighChartsData  :   "/Scripts/" +  "/HighCharts/modules/data",
              HighChartsDrilldown  :   "/Scripts/" +  "/HighCharts/modules/drilldown"
            }
            , shim : {
              main : {
                deps : ["HiChartsWithExtensions"]
              },
              HiChartsWithExtensions : {
                deps : ["HighChartsExporting","HighChartsData","HighChartsDrilldown"]
              },
              HighCharts: {
                deps : ["jquery"],
                exports: '$'
              },
              "HighChartsExporting" : {
                deps : ["HighCharts"]
              },
              "HighChartsData" : {
                deps : ["HighCharts"]
              },
              "HighChartsDrilldown" : {
                deps : ["HighCharts"]
              }
            }
});
window["require"](['main']);
```